# Modeling POCO According to Kendo-DataViz Stacked Chart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, kendo-dataviz

I have one issue while creating POCO classes to work with Kendo-DataViz.

We want to create stacked chart with using MVC wrapper and in the sample of Kendo it shows some static value like

```
     .Column(new int[] { 1100941, 1139797, 1172929, 1184435, 1184654 }).Stack(true)
     .Column(new int[] { 810169, 883051, 942151, 1001395, 1184654  }).Stack(true)
```

now this will create 5 Bars with each bar stacked with one more data and each value in 
int array corresponds to different bar and each index in all array corresponds to same bar

i.e :      **1100941**  and **810169** corresponds to first bar **bar1**.

So how to model this static data into POCO classes and fill the data.

i have created POCO as below

```
    public class TroubleFound
    {
    //Service center Name for which trouble is found
    public string ServiceCenterName { get; set; }
    //Which type of trouble is found
    public string TroubleFoundName { get; set; }
    //total count of trouble found
    public List<int> TroubleFoundCount { get; set; }
    }
```

but it's not working because it created one columns for each bar rather stacks on single bar

```
    series.Bar(data.TroubleFoundCount)
```

so how to Create POCO and fill it according to Kendo-Dataviz

Please refer http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/bar-charts/stacked-bar.html for what actually i want to develop.

Comment: the info is a bit disconnected, as if there's a chunk of logic missing between the `.Column()` stuff and the `base.Bar()` section. it's quite impossible to determine anything from your question, even tho the temptation is there to say try `.Column(data.TroubleFoundCount).Stack(true)`. try to show how this all fits together and i'm certain an answer will be forthcoming

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something very similar but with columns. I believe you can switch the series type from column to bar without any other changes.
Here is the model we used:

```
public class KendoStackedColumnChartModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<KendoStackedColumnModel> StackedColumns { get; set; }

    public class KendoStackedColumnModel
    {
        public string StackName { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<KendoColumnModel> Columns { get; set; }

        public class KendoColumnModel
        {
            public decimal Value { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }

    }

}
```

and in the wrapper:

```
        .Series(series =>
        {
            foreach (WebUI.Models.KendoStackedColumnChartModel.KendoStackedColumnModel stacked in Model.StackedColumns)
            {
                series.Column(stacked.Columns).CategoryField("CategoryLabel").Field("Value").Name(stacked.StackName).Color(stacked.Colour);
            }
        } 
    )
    .SeriesColors(new string[] { "#20BDFF", "#84DAFF", "#FFCD8A", "#FE9915", "#FF6633" })
```

Hope this helps someone else save some time...